# Python match a ipaddress with a subnet

Tags: python, dataframe, csv, ip-address

I've two csv file. File A contains a list of ipaddress and file B contains a list of subnets.
The condition is to find a match for ipaddresses. And append the matched subnets by creating a new column in File A

I tried

```
for i in df_1['ipaddress'].dropna():
   for j in df_2['Subnet'].dropna():
      if ipaddress.ip_address(i) in ipaddress.ip_network(j):
        df_1['ipaddress'] = i
        df_1['Subnet Match'] = j
      else:
        df_1['ipaddress'] = i
        df_1['Subnet Match'] = 0
```

But the challenge I face is when adding to csv it did not got into the if statement and in the csv file 0 is reflected. I need to add the matched subnet in the new column and if an ipaddress has no match 0 has to added.

Comment: What do you expect `df_1['ipaddress'] = i` and `df_1['Subnet Match'] = 0` to do? That's assigning the value to the _entire_ column. So regardless of what are in all your other row, only the result of the last one will survive.